# Crystal Reports running slow in application

Tags: performance, crystal-reports, report

In our application we use crystal reports to render the reports. There is a kind of weird behavior like the reports take longer time on the first run and faster from second. But this is also highly inconsistent when we run with different filter conditions. What all could be the problem and things to be checked. Any solution is highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the reports are cached? The program checks the chache, and if the report is in cache it returns that.

Comment: Is this on the Desktop? First report will take longer due to loading of all the massive Crystal Libraries.

Comment: Additionally first run of report may load printer drivers. What more - our application for example forces crystal component to verify database structure on first run, this takes additional time. Then it could be SQL server being underpowered :)

Answer (score 0):

When you design the report, before saving try to uncheck `save data with report`.  Maybe that can increase the speed.

Answer (score 0):

Some years ago I've had the same problem. I tried to load a dummy report on startup, but without much effect. It turned out that the crystal components tried to connect a verisign URL which was blocked by the firewall appliance of my customer, so that Crystal waited until this connection timed out.